# No module named 'gi'

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, modules

Recently i have installed `Altinstall` Python 3.8.0 in /usr/bin. However when i try to `from gi.repository import GLib` i get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`

I have tried many ways (including`import gi` but didn't work out. And i couldn't find the right resource explaining on this.

Any tips / guides?

*Raspbian Stretch*

Comment: Maybe this can help with your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall

Comment: @Pokebab thanks for the guide. I did Altinstall. Should i go for make install instead? I have successfully installed py3.8 in /usr/bin but unable to import gi again. Also i need to use future_fstrings and other new functions for manipulations . Awaiting you reply :)

Comment: What is `Altinstall`? Do you compiled python 3.8.0 from source? If so, please ask at https://stackoverflow.com/. It does not belong to Raspberry Pi. Or use an up to date Raspberry Pi OS Buster.

Answer (score 1):

On Raspberry Pi , I have always found the standard instructions for Debian work for the `gi` package
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#ubuntu-getting-started